# Why the HTML entities are getting displayed on iPhone/iPhone simulator even after removing them using PHP?

Tags: php, iphone, json, html-entities, stripslashes

I'm sending a JSON encoded response to the request coming from iPhone. In few of the values some HTML entities are present. I tried using [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.stripslashes.php) and [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.html-entity-decode.php) on such values. In browser I'm able to get the proper JSON response i.e. without these HTML entities but when the same response is seen on iPhone or iPhone simulator the HTML entities displayed again.

How should I resolve this issue? Can someone please help?

If you wan I can provide you the necessary code.

Thanks.

Comment: We definitely need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to debug it, but it sounds like it might be a caching issue.

Comment: Just make sure that you have set the header document type to `header('Content-Type: application/json');` if not. But it is good if you can provide the code.

Comment: Show us what is being sent to the phone.
Also a link to a screenshot of the phone or something would help

Comment: Are you running those functions on individual values prior to json encoding as opposed to running them on the whole json string (post-encoding). If doing it after, that is wrong. There's not enough information in the question for us to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

What about using http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php?

> This function tries to return a string with all NULL bytes, HTML and
>   PHP tags stripped from a given str

Answer (score 2):

in `PHP`

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('test' => html_entity_decode("Hello &#8211; World", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')));
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/0kwEVDFD):

```
{"test":"Hello \u2013 World"}
```

in `JS`:

```
var o = jQuery.parseJSON('{"test":"Hello \u2013 World"}');
alert( o.test );
```

[Output](http://jsfiddle.net/17ycs1st/):

```
Hello – World
```

Answer (score 1):

check out https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m from Converting & to & in Objective-C

A NSString category called "GTMNSString+HTML" written by Google works too. Check it out here: gist.github.com/takuma104/ntlniph/blob/master/gtm/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.h & here: gist.github.com/takuma104/ntlniph/blob/master/gtm/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.m